# What does <exclude>**.*</exclude> mean in maven syntax?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

EDIT 1:

The following code aims to package the source code without the resource files. But I don't know the meaning of **.* here.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <attach>true</attach>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you put here example of each syntax portion of code?

Comment: I've added some code for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see the apache maven doc here : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

It explain what difference between `**.*` and `**/*` !
Actualy, `**/*` is about *sub-folder exclusion*.

You can make combination of the both syntax, like this for example :

```
<exclude>**/*test*.*</exclude>
```

It will exclude all files in subfolders with `test` in filename

Comment: The doc explains the usage of `**/*`. But i still don't know why `**.*` can exclude all resource files rather than source files.

Comment: `**.*` is simply *all* files

Comment: But the source files still remain. Only resource files are excluded.

Comment: Yes, it is only for resource files (plugins).